# How can I alter a user defined type and have it propagate through my tables?

Tags: cassandra, alter-table, user-defined-types

I am trying to update a user defined type in Cassandra with a renamed field. This is my alter statement.

```
ALTER TYPE test.test_type RENAME a TO b;
```

This works fine and doing `DESC TYPE test.test_type` shows me the new schema. But I have a table with a schema like

```
col1 text PRIMARY KEY
col2 frozen<test_type>
```

and this does not seem to have been updated.

If I run `SELECT * FROM test_table` I get the old type fields

```
c1      | c2
--------+------------
value1  | {a: 'a1'}
```

If I try to insert, I am forced to use the new type

```
INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2) VALUES ('value2', {a: 'a2'});
```

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown field 'a' in value of user defined type test_type"

But even when I insert with the new type, I still get the old fields.

```
INSERT INTO test_table (c1, c2) VALUES ('value2', {b: 'a2'});
SELECT * FROM test_table;

c1      | c2
--------+------------
value1  | {a: 'a1'}
value2  | {a: 'a2'}
```

I've also tried running `ALTER TABLE` to re-type the column with the new type, adding a new column to the table with type `frozen<test_type>`, and even dropping the table and recreating it (which isn't even an option in production). No matter what, the type stays the same when I select from it.

How am I supposed to actually change the type?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me but I can't find any Jira's mentioning it. I'm getting the same results as you on Cass 2.1, CQL 3.2. Even creating a new table with the updated type has issues. Inserting uses the updated format, Selecting uses the original.

Comment: @AlecCollier Well that's sort of frustrating. I get the same behavior when doing `ALTER TYPE test_type ADD c text`. I'm a little surprised because I don't really see what the point of the `ALTER TYPE` statement is if it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue is logged in this Jira. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9188

Restarting cqlsh will return the values that you expect. The underlying table and type has been properly modified, it's just that cqlsh has a bug where it will not return the update values until cqlsh is restarted.

Comment: Awesome, you are correct. Thanks for figuring that out.